# Calculate the current week number between a daterange in ios

Tags: ios, swift, nsdatecomponents

**I know how to calculate total number of weeks between two date ranges.**

```
func calculateNoOfWeeksWith(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let dateFrom = calendar.startOfDay(for: startDate)
    let dateTo = calendar.startOfDay(for: endDate)

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: dateFrom, to: dateTo)

    return components.weekOfYear ?? 0
 }
```

I also know how to calculate the current week number(today) of a year.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let weekOfYear = calendar.component(.weekOfYear, from: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0))
print(weekOfYear)
```

But how can I calculate the current week number(today) between two date ranges instead of a year?

I mean if I select dates between 2020-03-27 & 2020-09-07 it will return 25 weeks. But **if I want to know what will be the week number of this current week then how are we going to do that?**

Comment: Calculate week# for start date (w1) and then for current date (w2) and subtract them, w2-w1 (add 1 if you want the first week to be 1 rather than 0).

Comment: Thanks. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

So, according to @JoakimDanielson 's suggestion the answer should look like this:

```
func calculateCurrentWeekNumberWith(startDate: Date, endDate: Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)) -> Int {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.firstWeekday = 2 //Monday
    calendar.locale = Locale.current  //Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    let weekNumberForStartDate = calendar.component(.weekOfYear, from: startDate)
    let weekNumberForEndDate = calendar.component(.weekOfYear, from: endDate)

   let currentWeekNum = weekNumberForEndDate - weekNumberForStartDate

   return currentWeekNum
   //return currentWeekNum+1 // Why added 1, because the difference between 2020-03-16 & 20-03-27 is 1 but we know it should be 2nd week. Also if you want the first week to be 1 rather than 0
}
```

Comment: This only works within a year.  Try: calculateCurrentWeekNumberWith(startDate: Date(), endDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(24 * 3600 * 400)